# Accessing SVN server from remote Ubuntu machine

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu

I have installed svn (Subversion) on one Ubuntu machine. Its locally working fine.
I want to access this svn repository from another Ubuntu machine.
Could anybody explain how to access svn repository from other client Ubuntu machines.
Note: Both the systems are in the same LAN.

EDIT (taken from answer added by OP)
Julien and jazzbassrob..thnks for your ans..

@jazzbassrob:
I tried with the "svn co .." command on the client machine, but i got ..

```
root@xyz:~# svn co svn://ipaddress/usr/local/svn/repos/test 
svn: /root/.subversion/config:16: Option expected
```

do we need to install svn on client side too..plz help

Comment: When updated with information, please edit the original question, rather than posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to configure a http access to your repository, [check this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion), it describes the way to install and configure the server (subversion and apache configuration)

Answer (score 0):

You simply use an SVN URL which uses the name or IP address of your server.  For example:

```
svn co svn://my-machine/path/to/svn/repos/project/trunk
```

The name of your machine is the bit after the '@' when you open a terminal.  Or, you can find the IP address of the machine by typing `ifconfig`.  For example, my IP address is 192.168.0.100:

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr --:--:--:--:--:--
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

As a further note, if you want to use a secure connection (i.e. svn+ssh://) you will need to configure an SSH server first.